Consulta sobre room y base de datos existente .db sqlite
quería saber si podrían orientarme sobre como lograr que room se conecte a mi base de datos guardada en la carpeta assets.
Ya he probado crear la bd con room y guardar pero requiero que mi app cuente con una bd preparada con información a consultar. Cualquier orientación. Ayuda a avanzar en este sentido libros o tutoriales se los agradecería. Espero ir montando de apoco el avance.
Por el momento ya arme la bd con db browser en sqlite

Hola, está explicado con bastante claridad en la documentación de Android. Debes fijarte en los ejemplos que usan el método createFromAsset()
